# Biblatex doesn't print entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

I am tring to make bibliographig list in Bibtex with subtitles. For this I have the following minimal example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{minimal.bib}
    @online{electronic1,
        author = {A. Author},
        title = {Funny website},
        urldate = {2013-01-09},
        url = {http://www.example.org},
    },
    @book{book1,
    author = {B. Bthor},
    title = {A Book of whatever},
    date = {2012},
    },
    @article{article1,
        author = {C. Cthor and D. Dthor},
        title = {Writing interesting articles},
        journaltitle = {The Journal of References},
        date = {2010-12-01},
    }
\end{filecontents}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Optionen zum Layout des Buchs                                     %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt
    liststotoc,                 % Abb.- und Tab.verzeichnis im Inhalt
    bibtotocnumbered
    listtotoc
    idxtotoc
    bibtotoc
]
{scrbook}

    \usepackage[
        natbib = true,
        style  = alphabetic
    ]{biblatex}

 \addbibresource{Literatur.bib}

\setuptoc{toc}{numbered}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx} %%Zum Laden von Grafiken

\begin{document}

\title{Minimalbeispiel zur Literaturverwendungsstyl ausprobung}
\author{Autor Anonymus}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents            % Inhaltsverzeichnis

\mainmatter                 % Vorspann (z.B. römische Seitenzahlen)
\chapter{Einleitung}

Bei der Book-Klasse des KOMA-Script wird durch den Gliederungsbefehl \verb#\frontmatter# automatisch auf römische Seitennummerierung gewechselt und die Nummerierung der Kapitel unterdrückt. In der Regel sollte der Vorspann nur aus einem Kapitel -- dem Vorwort -- bestehen. \cite{Kuester 2010}

Der Vorspann endet für scrbook, wenn durch \verb#\mainmatter# der Hauptteil beginnt.


\appendix                       % Beginn des Anhangs
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}
\listoftables               % Tabellenverzeichnis

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\listoffigures              % Abbildungsverzeichnis

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading                    % print heading for all bibliographies
\printbibliography[
        nottype = online,               % Put here verything that is NOT of the type "online".
                                                                        % The "electronic" type is just an alias to "online" 
        title={Quellen},     % title of the subbibliography
        heading=subbibliography         % make bibliography go one sectioning level lower
]
\printbibliography[
        type=online,                    % Put only references of the type "online" here.
        title={Online-Quellen},
        heading=subbibliography
]
\end{document}
```

I tried to compile 3 times, but it doesn't work.
My problem is that the entries doesent seem to be printed out to the pdf.

If you can help me, I would be happy.

Comment: Did you run biber after the first compilation?

Comment: its only one file, so the entries are in the "main" file. (if you meant that). Natbib is working behind

Comment: That's not what I mean. To build a document with `biblatex`, you should have to run `latex` -> `biber` -> `latex`. The `biber` step processes your references. See if this https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/105447 can help you.

Comment: `natbib` and `biblatex` are incompatible. With `natbib`, you had to call an extra program called `bibtex`. With your current setup, you need to call `biber`. See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber

Comment: You should also check out http://golatex.de/wichtige-hinweise-erstellung-von-literaturverzeichnissen-t11964.html

Comment: You need to run Biber instead of BibTeX. [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) gives a great explanation why you need to run Biber (or BibTeX) and gusbrs' link [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) explains how you get your editor to run Biber (instead of BibTeX, you'll still have to tell your editor to run the bibliography tool with F5 or F11 or whatever method your editor uses).

Comment: Ideally all the `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}` should not be needed because of the class options - they should already take care of that.

Comment: Any news here? Did you get anywhere? If not, what did you try and how did it not work for you?

Comment: Any news here? At the moment this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 and I will vote as such if the question is not edited in due time or you get back to us explaining why that did not work for you.

Comment: Any news here? As already mentioned, your question is currently for all we know a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: i did following changes in the code:

\usepackage[
 backend = biber,
 natbib  = true,
 style  = alphabetic,
 sorting = nyt
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib} 
Additionaly i changed the compile setting like, what  gusbrs recommended.